# General queries vs detailed queries to database

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm writing a web application in python and postgreSQL. Users are to access a lot of information during a session. All such information (almost) are indexed in the database. My question is, should I litter the code with specific queries, or is it better practice to query larger chunks of information, cashing it, and letting python process the chunk for finer pieces?

For example: A user is to ask for entries in a payment log. Either one writes a query asking for the specific entries requested, or one collect the payment history of the user and then use python to select the specific entries.

Of course cashing is preferred when working with heavy queries, but since nearly all my data is indexed, direct database access is fast and the cashing approach would not yield much if any extra speed. But are there other factors that may still render the cashing approach preferable?

Answer (score 1):

Database designers spend a lot of time on caching and optimization.  Unless you hit a specific problem, it's probably better to let the database do the database stuff, and your code do the rest instead of having your code try to take over some of the database functionality.